# How to create XML document with datatype using .NET or JAVA

Tags: java, .net, xml

I have a XSD for validating my XML document. This document I am generating/creating with the help of .NET/Java.

But after creating the XML document while validating it with the predefined XSD it is saying data types are not matching.

I need to create the XML with datatypes.

How to approach this problem? Any Documentation, Link would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the "Visual Studio" xsd.exe tool. Run this against your schema (it will create the classes representing it).

Then use an XmlSerializer or DataContractSerializer to serialize instances of your (generated) classes. 

That shoul do the trick,

Hope it helps,

Comment: If the classes are already created how to approach this? perhaps some modification?

Answer (score 2):

For Java, [JAXB](http://jaxb.dev.java.net) is the usual solution; lives under 'javax.xml.bind' package, and the reference implementation is even bundled with JDK 1.6 and above.
You can generate POJOs (that have appropriate annotations) from Schema, or Schema from annotated POJOs, and it is reasonably efficient as well when used correctly (avoiding use of DOM as input or output etc).